# Mongoose find() takes a few minutes before it returns latest documents

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mean-stack

If I add a document to the DB (either via my app, or via the DB admin tool RockMongo), I immediately see the documents being added to the DB (as shown by RockMongo), no problem. However, when I call a simple `model.find()` on the corresponding Mongoose model, the latest additions to the DB are not returned. They eventually show up after a couple of minutes.

It looks like the documents are being read from some kind of cache/buffer which isn't kept updated. Is there anything like that in Mongoose which I'm overlooking?

My backend is something like this:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
require('./models/Locations');
mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;
mongoose.connect(mongoUrl,{ config: { autoIndex: false } });
var Locations = mongoose.model('Locations');
[...]
app.get('/locations', function(req, res, next) 
{
    Locations.find(function(err, results)
    {
        if(err){return res.status(500).json(err);}
        res.json(results);
    });
});
```

The model:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

var LocationsSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: String
});

mongoose.model('Locations', LocationsSchema);
```

If I add an item to Locations manually in the DB, and point my browser to /locations, I don't see the new item until a few minutes later...

Comment: Not by default. Can you share your stack/configuration/code?

Comment: I have an app built on MEAN, with mongoldb v2.4.10, node v6, mongoose v4.6. I'll edit the question with some code. What's strange is that my app works fine on my machine, but not on the Gandi instance I setup...

Comment: MongoDB is very old. Take a look here, maybe this is a clue http://mongoosejs.com/docs/compatibility.html

Comment: That would explain why my local setup works, since I'm running v3.2.3...I didn't even think to check because I assumed creating an instance on Gandi would use a relatively recent mongoDB version by default

Comment: Did that answered your question?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't think so. Technically the link you sent shows that mongoDB v2.4 is compatible with mongoose v4.x, so I should be fine there. However, since that is one of the only config differences between my setup and the remote, it could still be related to the mongoDB version. What kind of caching/buffering could have been turned on by default in mongoDB or elsewhere without me noticing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's been a long time, but I noticed I never answered this question, so I thought I might in case someone else runs into this. It is very specific to my setup though. The issue was that Gandi uses a caching engine (Varnish) with relatively aggressive settings by default, leading to the slow update I was seeing in my webapp.

To solve this, one can explicitly set a header to deactivate the caching, for instance:

```
res.setHeader('Cache-Control', 'max-age=0');
```

Answer (score 0):

Change this:

```
Locations.find(function(err, results)
{
    if(err){return res.status(500).json(err);}
    res.json(results);
});
```

To this:

```
Locations.find({},function(err, results)
{
    if(err){return res.status(500).json(err);}
    res.json(results);
});
```